# Returning multiple checkboxes as array

Tags: jquery, html, forms, serialization, checkbox

I'm sure I'm doing something daft but I can't get my form to serialise multiple checkboxes in the way I want.

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pYrCL/3)

If you run, click populate form, tick a couple of boxes, then click serialise you get

an alert of `multi%5B%5D=1&multi%5B%5D=2`

when what I'm looking for is something more like `multi=1,2`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` — Trying to get a comma separated list instead of using the standard method used by forms and all form data parsers.

Comment: Ah, I see. Will php interpret them as an array at the other end if I POST that data?

Comment: The original data? Yes. The comma separated list? No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was being daft. Thought serialise created an array from checkbox values but turns out php does that on the server side when the checkboxes contain [] in the name attribute.